# Retriving POM files from Maven Repository

Tags: search, maven, nexus, pom.xml

I need to search for all POM files at Maven Repository. For this I used Nexus repository manager and its Rest API. I used keyword search where I went through all the letters and numbers separately. However I don't think that I got all the artifacts and their descriptions in this way. Is there any other solution to this? Or any proposals regarding my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are you forced to use the repository REST API? If you have access to the Nexus file system, a simple find command will do the job.

```
find /opt/sonatype-work/nexus/storage -name "*.pom"
```

Comment: I'm performing some data mining research so I'm building a software for information extraction(Java). That's why I'm in a need of complete artifact descriptions.